# How do I create 2 video tags without showing 2 videos?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can make reference to specific videos for 1 video tag and create another video tag without any videos in it so my variable knows it's a video. Problem with that is it creates a second blank video.

```
<video id="videoTag1" controls>
  <source id="mp4_src" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
  <source id="mp4_src" src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video id="videoTag2" controls>
</video>
```

How would I make reference that something is a video without using another video tag or switch to the 2nd tag without a blank second video popping up?

Comment: when you say "make reference that something is a video", are you trying to control it with backend functions or with css styles, for example? Can you clarify your goal?

Comment: Well I need the 2 tags to share 1 video layout instead of 2 where it would add a blank video. I think if I hide it, it wouldn't give the ability to replace the specific videos in a sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `src` in javascript:

```js
// Some example videos
const srcs = [
  'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4',
  'https://preview.redd.it/47zk247yufg31.gif?format=mp4&s=21e1fc3ab5d02d77762094026716fe5ae6fce0dc'
];

let video = document.getElementById('video');
let source = document.createElement('source');

// Set the inital video src and play
source.setAttribute('src', srcs[0]);
video.appendChild(source);
video.play();


let i = 1; // current index for example
// Update src and play
function changeVideo() {
  i = i ? 0 : 1;
  video.pause();
  source.setAttribute('src', srcs[i ? 0 : 1]);
  video.load();
  video.play();
}
```

```html
<video id="video" controls>
</video>
<button id="changeSource" onClick="changeVideo()">Change video</button>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Make the second video visibility set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide second video tag.

```
<video hide="true" id="videoTag2" controls>
```